# How to pass variable to a python cgi script

Tags: python, html, url, cgi

What I want to do is have a single python program in cgi-bin that is
executed by each of many pages on the site, and displays a line of HTML
on each page that is different for each file, but keyed to the URL of
that file on the site.

I know how to get the URL using javascript (e.g. on
http://constitution.org/cs_event.htm ):

```
<script language="javascript">
    var myurl = document.location.href;
    document.write(myurl);
</script>
<br>
<script language="javascript">
    var myurl = document.location.href;
    document.write("<A href=\"" + myurl + "\">" + myurl + "<\/A>");
</script>
```

And I know how to create a link that opens a page to execute the .py
script when one clicks on it:

```
<a href="http://constitution.org/cgi-bin/copy01.py?myurl=myurl">Here</a>
```

Here is the python script so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# This outputs a copyright notice to a web page

import cgi
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

thisurl = form.getvalue("myurl")

print """
<html><head></head>
<body>
"""

print """
Copyright &copy; 1995-2011 Constitution Society. Permission granted to copy with attribution for non-profit purposes.
"""

print """
</body></html>
"""

print thisurl
```

But it is not so obvious how to pass the variable value to the .py
script, and have it automatically display the URL of that page the way
the javascript does, or display a line of HTML that it will get from a
dictionary in which the URLs are the keys and the HTML lines are the data.

Ultimately, I want to be able to generate, using a single .py script,
all the footer content of each page, that can be maintained from a
single file that I can edit to make changes that propagate everywhere.

Comment: I found the way to get the URL of the calling page, which can be displayed with    import os  print os.environ['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: We still haven't solved the problem posed. I want something, such as a jquery script, that executes a python script that does nothing more than display a line of HTML chosen based on the url of the calling HTML page, a different line for each URL. Initially, it can show just the URL, but the eventual solution is to use the URL as a dictionary key to select the line as a value of that dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

CGI puts various things to do with the current request into the script's shell environment, which you can access in the normal way with `os.environ`. In particular, `os.environ['HTTP_HOST']` will get you the server name, and `os.environ['SCRIPT_NAME']` will get you the path.

Comment: That seems to get environment variables of the cgi script but not of the html page in which the call to the python script is embedded. I want that embedded call to it to immediately execute it the same way the javascript examples do, on the same page, without the user having to click on it.

Comment: In other words, I want the URL of the HTML page that calls the script, not that of the script itself. The script needs to get the URL of the calling HTML page, use it as a dictionary key to get the datum, which would be a line of HTML, and then immediately display that line in the calling HTML page, formatted as though it had been part of the HTML, with links, etc.